# How to test pyspark testcase for kafka write stream

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, pytest, apache-kafka-streams, testcase

I am trying to write a testcase for kafka write stream using pyspark and I am getting errors. AttributeError: type object 'StreamingContext' has no attribute 'awaitTermination'.
This is my function:

```
    
    def streamwriter(spark_stream):
    spark_stream.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("kafka").option(
                "header", True
            ).option(
                "kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
                f"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required  username=test_user password=test_password",
            ).option(
                "kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers
            ).option(
                "kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN"
            ).option(
                "kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"
            ).option(
                "checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_location}/{target_file_path}"
            ).option(
                "topic", kafka_topic
            ).trigger(
                processingTime="10 seconds"
            ).start().awaitTermination()
```

testcase for kafka write stream using pyspark

```
    @mock.patch("pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start")
    @mock.patch("pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.trigger")
    @mock.patch("pyspark.streaming.StreamingContext.awaitTermination")
    def test_kafka_writestream(
    get_secrets_mock,
    pyspark_option_mock,
    pyspark_write_mock,
    pyspark_start_mock,
    # pyspark_awaitTermination_mock,
    spark_session,
):
    spark = spark_session
    pyspark_start_mock.return_value = pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter
    pyspark_option_mock.return_value = pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter
    pyspark_write_mock.return_value = pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter
```

testcase for kafka write stream using pyspark

```
    kafka_utils.kafka_writestream(
        df_stream,
        SECRETS_ARN,
        SECRETS_REGION,
        KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
        checkpoint_location,
        target_file_path,
        KAFKA_TOPIC,
    )
    #option calls
    pyspark_option_mock.assert_has_calls(
        [
            call("header", True),
            call(
                "kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
                "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=test_api_key password=test_secret",
            ),
            call("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER),
            call("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN"),
            call("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"),
            call("checkpointLocation", "test_file_path/target_file_path"),
            call("topic", KAFKA_TOPIC),
        ]
    )
    pyspark_write_mock.assert_called_once()
    get_secrets_mock.assert_called_once_with(SECRETS_ARN, SECRETS_REGION)
```

Comment: How did you fixed it?